# Select from multiple rows based on values compare

Tags: sql

I have a table like below :

```
ID     Languages Experience  
1      c++       5
1      Java      2
1      Python    7
2      C#        1
2      c++       4
3      PHP       8
```

and so on.

I want a query to obtain specific ID depends on multiple unspecific conditions, for example :

**select ID that has languages php and Experience>3 and languages c++ and Experience<9**

Comment: Can you post which database you're using and what you're expected results are?  A little difficult to understand based on your post...

Answer (score 1):

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(case when languages = 'php' and experience > 3 then 1 end) > 0
and sum(case when languages = 'c++' and experience < 9 then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: This might be the correct answer, but given the sample data, would produce no results...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for using `or`:

```
select id
from yourtable
where (languages = 'PHP' and experience > 3)
   or (languages = 'c++' and experience < 9)
```

Comment: do you see any or on my statement?

Comment: @user3305603 -- given your sample data, without desired results, it's difficult to understand.  If you want ids that match both criteria, looks like you have an appropriate answer by juergen.  Given your sample data though, that would return no results so I was trying to infer what your question lacked...

Comment: and, at moments like these, when one is happily composing dynamic sql, is when one really, really needs to be careful with all the adhoc criteria being submitted by the users, to avoid sql injections.  This is more oriented to the OP than this answer.

Comment: @sgeddes, as you see the problem related to the title I need the condition across multiple rows then the criteria related in general to get data and apply the condition on mulitple row.

 select ID that has languages java and Experience>1 and languages c++ and Experience<1